# Update immutable object without breaking immutability

Tags: java, performance, scala, immutability, immutable-collections

how can I get updated immutable object from another immutable object without breaking the immutability in a good way. Something similar to how things are achieved in Scala or how they are achieved in Immutables library.

How can I achieve something like
 Customer.Builder.from(anotherCustomer).replaceOrder(oldOrder,newOrder).with(newName).build()

To reuse the old objects and queue all the changes I want in order to construct a new one.

I am using Java.

Comment: You can't, otherwise the object wouldn't be immutable anymore. You can create a modified copy, though.

Comment: How is your immutable object defined?  What language?  Give us some code and we can give you some advice.

Comment: Something like correcting a misspelled name? Serialize it, say to XML, do some magic, and deserialize it. The magic maybe being deserializing to a mutable form, but better working straight on the XML, or in the serialization.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
public class Customer {
    private String name;    
    private Order order

    private Customer(CustomerBuilder builder) {
        this.name = builder.name;
        this.order = builder.order;
    }

    public Customer replace(Order order) {
        return new CustomerBuilder().name(this.name).order(order).build();
    }

    public static class CustomerBuilder {
        private String name;    
        private Order order

        public CustomerBuilder name(String name) {
            this.name = name;
            return this;
        }

        public CustomerBuilder order(Order order) {
            this.order = order;
            return this;
        }

        public Customer build() {
            return new Customer(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not a good solution because for each change I need to construct a new object. I am looking more to queue commands until I say edit and than all changes be executed at once so that only 1 new object is constructed (apart from the updated ones).

Comment: Something like     Customer.Editor.name().order(editedOrder).addressRegistration(newAddress).edit();

Comment: it's exactly what you want, only the build() method triggers instantiation... This is a simple builder pattern, very common, the replace method however is a custom approach to fit your expectation

Answer (score 1):

I recommend this book who cover the subject : 
https://www.amazon.ca/Effective-Java-Edition-Joshua-Bloch/dp/0321356683

Best way I know to update immutable object is to return modified copy of the object, like java String

```
    String uppercase = "hello".toUpperCase()
```

I make easy to use fluent typing

```
    String uppercasewithoutletterL = "hello".toUpperCase().replace("L","")
```

Comment: Hello, lets suppose that I have a Builder that can build object from another object. Then I need to queue all the changes I want. For Example   Customer.Builder.from(anotherCustomer).replaceOrder(oldOrder,newOrder).build()    How do I do this ?

Comment: It is not builder pattern that I suggested but "functional method"
that return modified copy, I mean replaceOrder(old,new) return a new instance of Customer object.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a little recursive function that creates a changed immutable. It re-creates every nested object that includes the change.

```
const changeImmutable = (immutable: any, path: string[], newVal: any): any => {
  if(path.length) {
    let copy = Array.isArray(immutable) ? [...immutable] : {...immutable};
    copy[path[0]] = changeImmutable(copy[path[0]], path.slice(1), newVal);
    return copy;
  }
  return newVal; 
};
```

example of usage

```
let immutableObj = {a: {b: [{c: 'foo'}]}};

// change 'foo' to 'bar'
let newImmutableObj = changeImmutable(immutableObj, ['a', 'b', 0, 'c'], 'bar');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement [Cloneable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Cloneable.html) interface in object type. 
Another option is to have builder for your immutable objects which can create new instance from existing one. Something like [those](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3703519/is-this-a-valid-java-implementation-of-an-immutable-class-and-the-builder-patter) fellas done...